# Azure Shared Web Site mode and availability

Tags: azure

Taken from [How to Scale Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-scale-websites/#sharedmode):

> A web site running in Shared mode benefits from high availability even
>   with a single instance, but you can add up to 6 instances ("scale
>   out") for even greater performance and fault tolerance. For more
>   information, see "How to Change Scale Options for a Web Site" later in
>   this document.

Given the single-instance, shared web site scenario, how is the availability (uptime) affected by web site updates?

My previous Azure experience is based on Azure web roles, where a single instance means you get a long (read minutes) downtime for every update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're meaning updates in the sense of changes that you push to your site (as opposed to changes to the underlying technology by the Azure team), then my experience with websites has been of the order of seconds rather than minutes. If you're using Git for deployment via Github or Bitbucket, then it's the time taken to deploy the changes (around 30 seconds or so depending on the size of the site), plus the time taken for an App Pool recycle. It's usually all done within a couple of minutes.

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of change I meant.